# How to know a call is reaching voice mail in android

Tags: android

I would like to launch some other apps if my call is reaching others voicemail. How to detect it in android?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the broadcast of LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR and then act upon it

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR

You would extend PhoneStateListener and then initialize the class

```
public class VoicemailListener extends PhoneStateListener {

  private final Context context;

  public VoicemailListener(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged(boolean mwi) {
              //Message Recieved, do your work here
  }
}
```